Plain html as a landing page
I am currently working with reactjs, is it possible to have a plain html to be a landing page
Lets say i, when the user open xyzaa.com, it should show the plain static html from the public folder.
currently, i have this:
       
<Routes
           <Route path="/landing.html" onEnter={reload} />
</Routes>

this shows the landing.html,  it only when it when i type in url xyzaa.com/landing.html but i want to be the landing or the home page.

Does this answer your question? React: how to load and render external html file?

1- Rename your landing.html file to index.html.
2- Place index.html in the public folder of your React project.
3- Ensure any routes in your React app include a route for '/'.
This setup will make xyzaa.com load the index.html file by default.
